# Find existence of two integers in sequence that sum(a, b) = target

Tags: c

The task is:

> Input from file **input.txt** and output to file **output.txt**
>   The first line is target number.
>   The second line is sequence of positive integers in range `1` to `999999999`.
>
> If any two of these integers in sum equals to the target the program has to output 1 otherwise 0.

Example:

```
5
1 7 3 4 7 9
```

Output: `1`

There is my program. It pass 5 tests and fails the 6th - wrong result. I need help to find the bug or rewrite it.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fs = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    int target;
    fscanf(fs, "%d", &target);
    unsigned char bitset[1 + target / 8];

    int isFound = 0;

    for (int number; !isFound && fscanf(fs, "%d", &number) == 1;) {
        if (number <= target) {
            const int compliment = target - number;
            isFound = (bitset[compliment / 8] & (1 << (compliment % 8))) > 0;
            bitset[number / 8] |= 1 << (number % 8);
        }
    }
    fclose(fs);

    fs = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    fprintf(fs,"%d", isFound);
    fclose(fs);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is the input you've shown the one which produces the incorrect results? If not, please **edit your program** and include the data for which the program fails. Thanks.

Comment: I don't have access to the tests... :(

Comment: @Jegors Čemisovs It seems this declaration of an array unsigned char bitset[1 + target / 8] does not make sense.

Comment: I am very unfamiliar with C. I tried to implement in C my algorithm in Java: 
https://pastebin.com/sa0hWzHY

Comment: Originally I submit program in Java that uses regular Set. 
https://pastebin.com/spkFdQR9

This program works fine until stress test with big amount of data. The limit for the memory ONLY 65Mb and Java program exceed the limit. So I decided to rewrite it in C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, you forget to clear the local array, so you get undefined behavior and incorrect results. Note that variable sized arrays cannot be initialized with an initializer so you should use `memset` to clear this array.

The problem with this approach is `target` could be very large, up to `1999999997`, which makes it impractical to define a bit array of the necessary size with automatic storage. You should allocate this array with `calloc()` so it is initialized to `0`.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fs = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    unsigned long target, number;  /* type long has at least 32 bits */
    int isFound = 0;

    if (!fs || fscanf(fs, "%lu", &target) != 1)
        return 1;

    if (target <= 1999999998 && target / 8 < SIZE_MAX) {
        unsigned char *bitset = calloc(1, 1 + target / 8);
        if (bitset != NULL) {
            while (!isFound && fscanf(fs, "%lu", &number) == 1) {
                if (number <= target) {
                    unsigned long complement = target - number;
                    isFound = (bitset[complement / 8] >> (complement % 8)) & 1;
                    bitset[number / 8] |= 1 << (number % 8);
                }
            }
            free(bitset);
        }
    }
    fclose(fs);

    fs = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    fprintf(fs, "%d", isFound);
    fclose(fs);

    return 0;
}
```

For very large `target` values, a different approach can be used, using a hash table:

- read the next value `number`
- if `target-number` is in the hash table, found=1, stop
- if not, store number in the hash table
- continue

Comment: Interesting thing about `unsigned long` versus `unsigned` code change is that it really is the size of `size_t` that is needed to be at least 27+ bits for OP's approach to work.  IAC, good to make certain `target` is wide enough.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: indeed using type `unsigned long` fixed the potential portability issue to 16-bit targets, but these are quite likely to have 16-bit `size_t` as well. I added an extra test to avoid undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

At least this problem:

**Code attempts to read uninitialized data**

`bitset[]` not initialized.

```
isFound = (bitset[compliment / 8] ....
```

Suggest initializing:

```
 unsigned char bitset[1 + target / 8];
 memset(bitset, 0, sizeof bitset);
```

Comment: Thank you! It fix the problem. Now the program pass all tests.

Comment: @JegorsČemisovs Interesting that `bitset[number / 8] |= 1 << (number % 8);` needs to be after `isFound = (bitset[....`.  Took a while to see why.